# PropertyChanged event handler is always null

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, event-handling

When i first assign the bidning to the Label in its constructor, the Label binds correctly and displays correct information based on current ComponentData value of CurrentMarket class. However when ComponentData changes, OnPropertyChanged event fires ok, but the ProperyChanged handler is always NULL. Can someone kindly suggest what am i doing wrong?

I have a label and i set the binding like this:

```
    public StyledLabel(string Property, int i)
    {
        Binding BindingText = new System.Windows.Data.Binding(Property);
        BindingText.Source = Statics.CurrentMarket.ComponentData;
        BindingText.Converter = new TextConverter();
        this.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, BindingText);

     }
```

Current market class looks like this:

```
public class CurrentMarket : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string sMarket = "";
    ComponentData cComponentData;

    public string Market
    {
        set
        {
            sMarket = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Market");
            ComponentData = SharedBoxAdmin.Components[sMarket];
        }
        get
        {
            return sMarket;
        }
    }

    public ComponentData ComponentData
    {
        get { return cComponentData; }
        set
        {
            cComponentData = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ComponentData");
        }
    }

    public CurrentMarket()
    {
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the property name that you want to bind to as the `Path` of the `Binding` (rather than as part of the `Source`):

```
Binding BindingText = new System.Windows.Data.Binding(Property);
BindingText.Source = Statics.CurrentMarket;
BindingText.Path = new PropertyPath("ComponentData");
BindingText.Converter = new TextConverter();
this.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, BindingText);
```